# How do I put text before page number?

Tags: page-numbering

I need to put "H.S. -" before every page number. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753477/how-do-i-make-custom-page-numbering-in-latex ?

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot. Maybe I should've looked up more.

Comment: Can you specify what document class you're using? The answer may depend on it. The answers in the linked page are, in my opinion, rather bad and one reason is that the question was too generic.

Answer (score 5):

It is simplest to update `\thepage`:

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{H.S.~--~\arabic{page}}
```

This will be reflected wherever the page number is displayed, and even in references.

Comment: Simple, no extra package... what else you want...

Answer (score 4):

It is better to use `fancyhdr` for this.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
% New page style
\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{H. S. -- \thepage}  %% change [C] to either [L] or [R] if needed.
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@mypagestyle%% comment this to keep chapter page style
%\let\ps@empty\ps@mypagestyle
\makeatother
\pagestyle{mypagestyle}

\begin{document}
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your assertion that it is better to use a package is not backed in your answer. Can you state why? Werner's solution is much simple, and I fail to see why that would not be optimal.

Comment: @luchonacho: Read Werner's answer again: "This will be reflected wherever the page number is displayed, and even in references.". This can be trouble.